# I denied myself access to explorer.exe... (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, operating-system, registry, file-permissions

Somehow, I managed to lock myself away from explorer.exe. I can't open the start menu, *nevermind, win+r does work*, and when trying to launch explorer.exe via an icon I have on my task bar or via command line, I get an access denied error. System restore says it's unavailable on the system. Don't have access to the control panel either. I do have access to regedit and cmd/ps.

It all happened after I went to regedit and elevated permissions to all fo the root folders (just tried giving myself all the permissions to all fo the registry, tried changing as many "allow" as I could - don't ask plz...). I wanted to launch unity righjt afterwards but it wouldn't launch, so I restarted the PC. Once I logged back in, the issue was present. No explorer.exe for me. I tried granting myself permissions with icacl (:F) - access denied.

Please tell me there's something I can do to safe this situation...

**Adding more info for context:**

The exact error I'm getting when trying to launch explorer.exe reads:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not
> have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a third party firewall. explorer.exe wouldn't normally need to ask permission unless you had already restricted it or unless it is malware.

Note: The explorer.exe file is located in the folder C:\Windows. In other cases, explorer.exe is a virus, spyware, Trojan or worm!
Virus with same name:
W32.MyDoom.B - Symantec Corporation
and other...

Boot into Safe Mode

- Restart your computer and start pressing the F8 key on your keyboard.
- Select the Safe Mode option when the Windows Advanced Options menu appears, and then press ENTER.

Right click on Start>Explore> Windows> scroll down on the right side screen and right click on explorer.exe> Propertied> make sure it's identified as 'Windows Explorer.'

If ID is OK, open Programs section of the firewall and reset access for explorer.exe.

Comment: I cannot launch safe mode due to bitlocker (it's my company's machine...). I must admit I'd love to avoid going to IT with this issue cos I'm utterly ashamed of having caused this mess.
I cannot launch the firewall setting, either. Launching it via win+R or cmd gives no result (literally nothing is happening), and I cannot open the start menu or the control panel (turns out I don't have access to the control panel either).
I have access to regedit however, if this helps.

Comment: Disable this through a small registry tweak

Simply import the following to turn off the policy check:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE]
"RDVDenyWriteAccess"=dword:00000000

Import this snippet to revert back to the secure state:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE]
"RDVDenyWriteAccess"=dword:00000001

This is quite probably a breach in the security policy of your company. Use at your own risk.